# How to sort nested hashmaps?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

The `hashmap` below forms like a table with key-value pair strings. `Integer` represents row and column index respectively.

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>> fullMap = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>>();
```

How do I sort the innermost hashMap? sort row by keys ascending order

**unsorted output:**

```
.      0           1           2   
0  john,men     ace,his    hish,opt  
1  vrix,alt    home,jul     ics,ard
```

**sorted output:**

```
.      0           1           2   
0   ace,his     john,men    hish,opt 
1  home,jul      ics,ard    vrix,alt
```

Comment: you can't sort a hashmap. use some other implementationof map like treemap and then apply the custom sorting criteria.

Comment: @zombie. You can sort a hashmap (or any other collection) when you stream its values.

Comment: @sprinter Hey thanks, i don't know about this new interface of java 8. It returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source and then we sort the stream but the map itself is not sorted. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you sort your maps on use rather than change the way the data is stored.

If I understand your question, you wish to sort by the keys in the key-value pairs. If that is correct, then you can do:

```
void processRow(Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> row) {
    row.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .forEach(entry -> ...);
}
```

As an aside, your analogy of your data structure as a table is confusing. It's a map from int to int to string to string. This could represent a table where each cell is a list of key/value pairs. But that's a pretty unusual table.

A more conventional representation of a relational table would be something like `List<Map<Column,Value>>`.

Comment: i just would like to sort each row   alphabetically, say row 0 keys john,ace,hish as shown on the unsorted output will become row 0 ace,john,hish as shown on the sorted output

Comment: Ok I'll change my answer to match that

Answer (score 2):

Sorting of map entries based on keys can be achieved using TreeMap. Create HashMap< Integer,TreeMap< String, String>> to maintain column format.

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> treeMap1 = new TreeMap<>();
treeMap1.put("john","men");
treeMap1.put("ace","his");
treeMap1.put("hish", "opt");
Map<String, String> treeMap2 = new TreeMap<>();
treeMap2.put("vrix","alt");
treeMap2.put("home","jul");
treeMap2.put("ics", "ard");
map.put(1, treeMap1);
map.put(2, treeMap2);
```